# selenium webdriver send keys pycharm

Tags: selenium, webdriver, key, send

I have data in an excel sheet, first Column has a number, and second Column has text. My program works with text but not with numbers.

```
import xlrd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

print(driver.title)
search = driver.find_element_by_name("search_query")

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("mohammed2.xls")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("sheet3")

rowCount = sheet.nrows
colCount = sheet.ncols
print(rowCount)
print(colCount)
for curr_row in range(1, rowCount):
    numpValue = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 0)
    #name = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 1)
        
    search.send_keys(numpValue)
    time.sleep(3)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    search.clear()
    time.sleep(3)
    search.clear()
```

Comment: what error are you getting

Answer (score 1):

```
search.send_keys(str(numpValue))
```

it seems sendKeys doesn't allow float , and the value from number field is in folat formate